# ejabberd: installed, added users its working but ejabberdctl not working

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

installed ejabberd using synaptic package manager on Ubuntu 10.04 without any error.
"sudo dpkg-reconfigure ejabberd" used to configure it.
Added users too using http://localhost:5280/admin/ console. everything working fine except ejabberdctl command.

knocker@ps0714-U:~$ ejabberdctl

Failed RPC connection to the node 'ejabberd@ps0714-U': nodedown

knocker@ps0714-U:~$ ejabberdctl status

Failed RPC connection to the node 'ejabberd@ps0714-U': nodedown

knocker@ps0714-U:~$ ejabberdctl register test test

Failed RPC connection to the node 'ejabberd@ps0714-U': nodedown

is anything wrong in configuration? 
what i have missed here..?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add sudo on your command. Like so:

```
sudo ejabberdctl status
```

Comment: I was stuck at the same probelm can you explain what sudo does and why we added sudo here?

Comment: run as root [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)